# Moq a virtual ICollection<> property that has a private set : "Invalid setup on a non-virtual"

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, icollection

I'm running into a problem where I try to mock an object which contain a property `Items` of type `ICollection<>`. I get the following error :

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.Items

The problem is that the property **Items is already virtual**.

I reproduced the error that I get in my project, in the Sandbox below :

```
public class ItemList
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialList
{
    public virtual string Token { get; internal set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemList> Items { get; private set; }
}
```

That error occurs in my Test when I try to `SetupProperty` like that :

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestSpecialList
{
    [Test]
    public void Mocking_Virtual_ICollection()
    {
        var mockModel = new Mock<SpecialList>();
        var listItem = new List<ItemList> {new ItemList {Id = 007}};

        mockModel.SetupProperty(m => m.Items, listItem);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to Moq an object containing a ICollection<> property?

Comment: Can you do mockModel.object.items = listItem ?

Comment: @user1168234 Not in my case because the set has to be private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using either of these:

```
mockModel.Setup(m => m.Items).Returns(listItem);
mockModel.SetupGet(m => m.Items).Returns(listItem);
```

The method `SetupProperty` is used when you want to track its value, see [moq wiki](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart). Although I am not enterily sure why `SetupProperty` fails, as its intention is to be able to assing and retrieve the property value, it seems likely to be caused by the private get.

To be clear, let's assume your property has a public set. In that case when using `Setup` or `SetupGet`, doing something like `mockModel.Object.Items = new List<ItemList>();` would have no effect and you would still see the list with a single item. However with `SetupProperty` the same statement would have changed the value returned by the property.

Basically `SetupProperty` allows to get AND SET the value of a property and that's why I think it cannot be used with a private set.

Comment: Right, I made few tests and it seems the be the `private set` as you point me out, whereas if I made it internal, it works!!! Though I cannot make them internal, so I will test your solution.

Comment: @ForceMagic Great! just added some more info :)

Comment: It did works! :D Thanks a lot for clarifying concepts and for the quick answer. I did used Setup().Returns before, though I have no idea why I thought I couldn't use it again in this case.